# PyQt5: изменение элементов из не GUI файла

Tags: pyqt5

Привет. Есть файл с ui, который по кнопке запускает сокет сервер, тот периодически принимает данные и нужно, чтобы эта данные отображались в окне. Как получить доступ к лейблу из файла - сервера?